# Where did the $q^{1/8}$ factor in the Ramond sector come from?

Tags: string-theory, definition, conformal-field-theory

D-Branes Clifford Johnson page 116

> For the Ramond sector, the zero point energy of
> a single fermion is $1/24$. After multiplying by two, we see that this is again
> correctly obtained in our partition function, since $−1/24 + 1/8=1/12$. It
> is awfully nice that the function $f_2^2 (q)$ has the extra factor of $2q^{1/8}$, just
> for this purpose

where $f_2(q)$ was given

> $f_2(q)=\sqrt{2} q^{1/24} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+q)^n$

But $f_2^2(q)=2 q^{1/12} \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+q)^{2n}$ did not seem to contain the factor of the order $q^{1/8}$.

Where did the $q^{1/8}$ factor in the Ramond sector come from?